# Roots of a special polynomial

Tags: polynomials, roots

I have a question that seems tricky to me. So, let $P_n$ be the polynomial defined by $P_n(x+1/x)=x^n+x^{-n}$. And let $Q$ be some polynomial with $\sup_{x\in [-2,2]}|Q(x)|<2$. Then $P_n-Q$ has at least $n$ different roots. I have no idea yet. It's clear that $P_n(x)\notin (-2,2)$ für $x \notin (-2,2)$ but I don't see any use of it. I would be grateful for any idea.

Comment: $P_n$ is not an arbitrary polynomial but a concrete one which satisfies $P_n(x+1/x)=x^n+x^{-n}$. So they all have a concrete form. For example, $P_2(x)=x^2-2$, $P_3(x)=x^3-3x$ and so on. I doubt that there is a general formula for all $n$s.

Comment: You should look at the Chebychev polynomials.

Comment: Hm, I still don't get why $P_n(x)-Q$ has $n$ roots. Is it one of known properties of Chebyshov polynomials?

Comment: It's too long since I thought about them. I would look in Fox's book. https://books.google.co.uk/books/about/Chebyshev_polynomials_in_numerical_analy.html?id=F8NzsEtJCD0C&redir_esc=y

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint:

Let $t=x+1/x$. Resolving the equation with respect to $x$ one obtains: 
$$
x_\pm=\frac{t\pm\sqrt{t^2-4}}{2}.
$$
Notice: $x_+=x^{-1}_-$.

Thus:
$$
P_n(x)=\left(\frac{x+\sqrt{x^2-4}}{2}\right)^n+\left(\frac{x-\sqrt{x^2-4}}{2}\right)^n.\tag{1}
$$

Observe that upon binomial expansion of both summands the odd powers of $\sqrt{x^2-4}$ will cancel, so that the function (1) is indeed a polynomial of order $n$.

Next observe that there can be no real roots of the polynomial outside the interval $(-2,2)$ as both summands are real and have the same sign. Inside the interval one can use the substitution $x=2\cos t$ to obtain:
$$
P_n(2\cos t)=e^{itn}+e^{-itn}=2\cos nt,\text{ with } 0\le t\le\pi.  
$$
The function obviously has $n$ distinct real roots $t_k=\frac{2k+1}{2n}\pi$ with $k=0..(n-1)$. Recalling that the power of $P_n(x)$ is $n$ they represent the complete list of roots of the polynomial.

Besides the following inequality holds for all $-2\le x \le 2$:
$$
-2\le P_n(x)\le 2,
$$
with limits being attained at $x=2\cos\frac{2k+1}{n}\pi$ and $x=2\cos\frac{2k}{n}\pi$, respectively.

Comment: Thank You but on this way we can only define $P_n$ outside of $[-2,2]$. How can it help me to show that $P_n-Q$ has $n$ different roots in $[-2,2]$? Should I really go to the complex plane? I wanted actually to solve it remaining on the real axis.

Comment: @Logic_Problem_42 I have extended the hint.